# how to add percentage completion on parallel nested loops?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

for example, i wish I can see 1% ~ 100%, how could I do that?

```
Parallel.For<Dictionary<int, long>>(0, r1, () => new Dictionary<int, long>(), (j, loop, tmpWinRange) =>
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < r2; k++)
            for (int l = 0; l < r3; l++)
                for (int m = 0; m < r4; m++)
                {
                    int pay = GetPay(j, k, l, m);
                    tmpWinRange[pay]++;
                }
        return tmpWinRange;
    },
(x) => { tmpWinRangeCollection.Add(x); }
);
```

Comment: How big is `r1`? Is it enough to change the progress every time the outer-most loop (the one with `j`) finishes?

Comment: @svick   r1, r2,r3,r4 are roughly in range 20~100

Answer (score 0):

How about using an interlocked increment to update the progress?

```
int progressCount = 0;
Parallel.For<Dictionary<int, long>>(0, r1, () => new Dictionary<int, long>(), 
    (j, loop, tmpWinRange) => 
    { 
        for (int k = 0; k < r2; k++) 
            for (int l = 0; l < r3; l++) 
                for (int m = 0; m < r4; m++) 
                { 
                    int pay = GetPay(j, k, l, m); 
                    tmpWinRange[pay]++; 
                }
        Interlocked.Increment(ref progressCount);

        return tmpWinRange; 
    }, 
    (x) => { tmpWinRangeCollection.Add(x); } 
);
```